# When used with "ORDER BY", does "TOP" clause return a table (i.e. rows returned are NOT ordered) or a cursor (i.e. rows returned are ordered)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been reading "tsql fundamental" by Ben Itzik.

I have encountered the following phrase in the section about "TOP" clause

[image]

However, the author did not specify whether the TOP clause return a table or a cursor.

So what exactly does "TOP" clause return?

Comment: The top clause limits the number of rows returned by a select statement.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank you for the comment. I understand that top clause limit the number of returned rows, but after top clause is processed, is the resulting table a relational table (i.e. rows returned are not ordered) or a cursor (i.e. rows returned are ordered)? Could you help me out?

Comment: `TOP` never "returns a `CURSOR`" as we know it in current versions of T-SQL. therefore without being familiar with the meaning and context of "cursor" as it is obviously used in this book, the question sounds confusing to me. TOP alone does not imply an `ORDER BY`, so you can not rely on any particular set or order of results from `SELECT TOP` queries when you don't explicitely order them.

Comment: @dlatikay thank you for the clarification. I understand that when used along, TOP clause does not impose any order. I have modified the title of the question, i.e. added the words "when used with ORDER BY clause".

Comment: so what i'm trying to ask is: when used with ORDER BY, does TOP clause return a table or a cursor?

Comment: since ORDER BY clause impose ordering to the rows and return a cursor, so if the TOP clause operate on a cursor (because TOP is executed after ORDER BY), does TOP return a table or a cursor?

Comment: @dlatikay the book is not talking about TSQL cursor. Search for the word "cursor" on this page http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/deprecated-t-sql-features to see how the term is being used.

Comment: It depends where the `TOP ... ORDER BY` is in the query.

If it is at the outer level then rows returned are guaranteed to be ordered. If it is in a table expression then there is no such guarantee.

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you so much!! so lucky to have experts in the field helping out on stackoverflow. Can't appreciate your help enough